# Name of larger ball with smaller ball removed

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $B_n (R)$ be the $n$-ball with radius $R$ around the origin. Does the construct $B_n (R_1) - B_n (R_2)$, where $R_1 > R_2$ has a name? I am inclined to call it a shell, but I am not sure.

Comment: yeah its a shell lol

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's often called an annulus.

Comment: Are the balls concentric?

Comment: @Arthur the balls are constructed around the origin such that $||\mathbf{r}|| < R$

Comment: Usually the notation is $B_r(x)$ and it denotes the ball of radius $r$ around the point $x$. Your notation doesn't make much sense, admittedly.

Comment: In higher dimensions it is also frequently called an annulus (at least by topologists).

Comment: I also know this set as an annulus. @AsafKaragila : I believe the OP uses the $-$ sign for set difference...where did you get the $x$ from?

Comment: @haemi yes, I mean it as a set.

Comment: @user110971 Then it's definitely an annulus, or perhaps you could call it a ring...